# stop audio player when adapter is closed in android app

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, audio, flipview

I am developing an android app in which a user is able to read books and listen to the recorded audio for that book. I am using a Flip view to toggle between the pages.

**Here's my main activity:**

```
private class FullBook extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Personal_Library_Click.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id", userId));
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("book_id", BookIdpref));

            json = jParse.makeHttpRequest(url_getBook, "GET", params);

            try {

                JSONArray jsonary = json.getJSONArray("list");

                Log.e("This is the books response", " " + json);

                arrayVideos = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonary.length(); i++) {

                    hashVideos = new HashMap<String, String>();


                    JSONObject local_obj = (JSONObject) jsonary.get(i);

                    if (local_obj.toString().contains("image")) {
                        Image = local_obj.getString("image");
                        hashVideos.put("image", Image);
                    }

                    if (local_obj.toString().contains("image_id")) {
                        ImId = local_obj.getString("image_id");
                        hashVideos.put("imageId", ImId);

                    }

                    Log.e("Image ID : ", " " + ImId);

                    arrayVideos.add(hashVideos);

                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);
            pDialog.dismiss();

            flipView.setAdapter(new FlipAdapter(Personal_Library_Click.this, arrayVideos));

        }
    }
```

***And hers is my Adapter :***

```
public class FlipAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener {

public interface Callback {
}

private LayoutInflater inflater;
private Callback callback;
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
public lazyloading.ImageLoader imageLoader;
private Activity activity;

MediaPlayer mp;

public FlipAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
    activity = a;

    data = d;
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader = new lazyloading.ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());

}

public void setCallback(Callback callback) {
    this.callback = callback;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return data.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if(convertView == null){
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.page_flip, parent, false);

        HashMap<String, String> hashmaparray = new HashMap<String, String>();
        hashmaparray = data.get(position);


        holder.BookPages = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.book_page);
        holder.ShowVideo = (VideoView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.show_video);
        holder.ShowVideo.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

        if(activity.toString().contains("Personal_Library_Click")){

            String image =hashmaparray.get("image");

            imageLoader.DisplayImage(image, holder.BookPages);

        }

        if(activity.toString().contains("AdminBookFlip")){

            String im = hashmaparray.get("image");
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(im, holder.BookPages);

            String v = hashmaparray.get("video");

            mp=new MediaPlayer();

            try{
                mp.setDataSource(v);//Write your location here
                mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();

            }catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

        if(activity.toString().contains("ViewBookVideo")) {

            String im = hashmaparray.get("image");
            imageLoader.DisplayImage(im, holder.BookPages);
        }

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }else{

        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

    }

    //TODO set a text with the id as well

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder{
    ImageView BookPages;
    VideoView ShowVideo;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch(v.getId()){
    }
}

}
```

When I open this activity it runs perfectly. But when I close the activity the audio keeps running at the background. I need to stop the audio when I go back from this activity. I tried to make the adapter null onBackPressed() but that didn't work. Can any one please guide me to solve this issue? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pass MediaPlayer Object in your adapter class object and use that object in adapter

```
MediaPlayer mp=new MediaPlayer();

flipView.setAdapter(new FlipAdapter(Personal_Library_Click.this, arrayVideos, mp));//mp is Mediaplayer object


 //Stop Audio

  @Override
  public void onPause(){
     //media player stops
     super.onPause();
 }
```

Comment: Hi Tejas...!! Thanks, i will try this.

Comment: same problem create again ?

Comment: Hi Tejas..!! Yes the problem still persists. I tried your solution but didn't work for me. I don't know why it is happening. I have tried to call mp.stop() on all the methods onPause(). onStop(), OnResume(), onDestroy() but nothing has wored till now.

Answer (score 0):

At first in my opinion you shouldn't do this in Adapter.
Fragment/Activity is better place for it.
Then you have method like **onPause** and **onResume** which is the best place to start and stop MediaPlayer.

```
private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
@Override
public void onPause(){
    //media player stops
    super.onPause();
}
@Override
public void onResume(){
    //mediaPlayer initialize and start
    super.onResume();
}
```

Comment: Hi J.D. I have already tried this but didn't work for me. Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: I was thinking a little more about it and I tried to use it in a simple project. It is basically working fine for me when you properly handling mediaPlayer and have proper mp3 with keyframes inside.
Please try to use `mediaPlayer.pause()` from onPause method. Should really work for you. You can even have some `adapter.stopMusic()` method and call it from `onPause()` if you wish.

Comment: Hi J.D. I tried this method earlier, even made a method in which i am calling the mp.stop(), and call that method in onBackPressed(). in my Activity. When i tried to debug the class i found that the method is being called onBackPressed() but the audio is still going on at the backend. I will try to put the adpater.stopMusic() method as you said above and let you know if that works or not. Thank you so much for your help. :)